# Tensorflow tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy() is only utilizing one GPU

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm using tensorflow-gpu 1.13.1 with 2 x RTX2080-Ti. I was hoping to run the training code with 2 GPUs using tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(), but it turns out using one GPU. My training model looks like:

```
for A in range(0, outer_loop):
    load_database = Load_database  # <Load database>
    for B in range(0, inner_loop):
        X_train, X_valid, Y_train, Y_valid = load_data  # <Load Data>
        self = Model(hyperparam)   
        model = self.create()  # <create model>
        epoch = 0
        for epoch in range(max_epoch):
            hist = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=200, verbose=1)
            loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(x=X_train, y=Y_train)
            Y_train_predict = model.predict(x=X_train)
```

Model creation is written in a separate file which is as follow:

```
Class Model():
    def create_model():
        # <configure layer parameters>
    def create():
        self.num_classes = num_classes

        # Create graph and session
        tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()
        gpu_options = tf.compat.v1.GPUOptions()
        config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=False, gpu_options=gpu_options)
        config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
        tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
        self.graph = tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph()
        self.sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)

        with self.graph.as_default():
            with self.sess.as_default():
                with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope(tf.compat.v1.get_variable_scope()):
                    x = Input(shape=(800, 6, 1), name='X')
                    self.y_ = self.create_model(x)
                    self.scope()
                    strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(devices=["/gpu:0","/gpu:1"],                                                              cross_device_ops=tf.contrib.distribute.AllReduceCrossDeviceOps(all_reduce_alg="hierarchical_copy"))
                    with strategy.scope():
                        model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[x], outputs=[self.y_])
                        model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=self.optimizer, metrics=[self.metrics])

        return model
```

As written above, I tried to wrap model.compile part with strategy.scope() to use two GPUs. The code run without any error, but when I check GPU utilization, only one GPU is being loaded and the other one is at rest as below.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 525.60.13    Driver Version: 525.60.13    CUDA Version: 12.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  On   | 00000000:0A:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 43%   84C    P2   225W / 250W |  10915MiB / 11264MiB |     90%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  NVIDIA GeForce ...  On   | 00000000:42:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 28%   39C    P8    17W / 250W |    161MiB / 11264MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Could anyone let me know what might be the cause for this?

I tired wrap the entire main training loop but it didn't help either.

Comment: `tf.compat.v1` does not exist in tf 1.13. Can you check which version of TF you're using?

Comment: Hi @Lescurel, I think I'm using 1.13.1. When I export my interpreter to yml, I get the following tensorflow related extensions:

  - tflow_select=2.1.0=gpu
  - tensorboard=1.13.1=py36h33f27b4_0
  - tensorflow=1.13.1=gpu_py36h9006a92_0
  - tensorflow-base=1.13.1=gpu_py36h871c8ca_0
  - tensorflow-estimator=1.13.0=py_0
  - tensorflow-gpu=1.13.1=h0d30ee6_0

Comment: Now I changed it to v2.12.0 and checked it's working with 1 gpu, but still using multiple gpus causing the same problem. Can anyone help me fixing this?